# Custom Action Filter ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This thing is killing me. Basically what I have is the custom ActionFilter (Class which Inherits from ActionFilterAttribute and implements IActionFilter). it looks like this

```
public class ValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // do some stuff here
    }
}
```

this is what FilterConfig looks like

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new ValidationFilterAttribute());
    }
}
```

But whenever I start the project there is an exception saying following

The given filter instance must implement one or more of the following filter interfaces: IAuthorizationFilter, IActionFilter, IResultFilter, IExceptionFilter.

But obviously the `ValidationFilterAttribute` implements one of those interfaces. Am I missing something very basic here? I can't figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prefix your base class with `System.Web.Mvc`, I have a "hunch" you may be using `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute` instead.

So then you would have to override

```
OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
```

And things will be OK.

And as you can see, `ActionFilterAttribute` implements `IActionFilter` already, so you don't need to specify it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you don't need the `IActionFilter` declaration.
`ActionFilterAttribute` already implements `IActionFilter`

But I don't know if this is the cause of the error message. Could you try removing it?

Check this also: http://forums.asp.net/t/1835666.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
[Serializable] public class RedirectingAction : ActionFilterAttribute
{ 
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) { base.OnActionExecuting(context); 

}
```

after that use this attributes in your controller like below

```
[RedirectingAction] 
public class HomeController : BaseController { }
```

custom action filter example by www.jkittraining.com
   www.jkittraining.com/course/asp-net-mvc-training/